# Is TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA equivalent to SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Tags: java, security, sockets, ssl, encryption

I am working on configuring a Java client which its job is to make TLS connections to servers. I want to configure my client with these 3 ciphers:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
```

In Java supported cipher suites, I found the same ciphers but with SSL at the beginning NOT TLS. The question, if I configured my client with:

```
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
```

Are the two lists exactly the same and will be interpreted by the server same? I am worried if I configured the client with `SSL_*` ciphers this mean something different than `TLS_*` and may be some servers do not support `SSL_*`. How can I be sure?

Comment: Please don't do this unless you know exactly what you are doing and are committed to keeping your software up to date. If you go down this path it's all too easy for your software to end up with a hardcoded list of supported ciphersuites none of which are recommended anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. See [Java Cryptography Architecture
Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites):

> Some JSSE cipher suite names were defined before TLSv1.0 was finalized, and were therefore given the `SSL_` prefix. The names mentioned in the TLS RFCs prefixed with `TLS_` are functionally equivalent to the JSSE cipher suites prefixed with `SSL_`.